# Contact picture not connect with Faces on Photo

Tags: photos, contacts

Each time I'm going to select a face picture for my contact in the MacBook Pro (Mid. 2010 OS X 10.11) and I select the option `Faces` the window display the following message:

```
Find and organise photos of <name_of_the_contact> in the photo app using Faces.
```

The problem here is that I would like to choose a photo among the available pics in the Photo app for my contacts. Obviously I set one pics in the app Photo but these are not present in the list when I edit the photo in the contacts app. The two app appear to be not related each other.

Someone have had the same problem and maybe solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have hit the difference between the old handling of Faces & the new.

If your Face is tagged as 'john', & 'john' is not in your Contacts list, it cannot find him.
If he's tagged as John Smith - john.smith@me.com then he can be found.

The only way to associate the two is to click the name under the face in Photos, start typing the name, then pick john.smith@me.com instead of just 'john'.

Then when you go back to Contacts, it can associate the Faces selection with the appropriate Contact.

Here's an example using some Davids - the top ones are my 'Faces' as I already have them; underneath are the same people as 'Contacts' which is imho a lot less 'chummy' but how you must tag people before they will correctly link as Contacts.

[image]

Comment: I tried but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: then… you did it wrong, In the above pictorial example, completing that 'Face' by selecting 'David K' will not work in Contacts. Selecting 'david[blur] @ .co.uk will then allow Contacts to associate the photos. It's immediate, you don't even need to relaunch either app.